# Qt: The child dialog moves with the parent dialog (no delay)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a child dialog and a parent dialog. I want the child dialog to follow the parent dialog to move;

my current plan is to override `moveEvent（）` in the parent dialog, but the effect is not good: **the child dialog moves delay**. Is there a better solution？

***Update:***

**platform:macos**

atomwindow.h

```
class atomwindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit atomwindow(QDialog *parent = nullptr);
    ~atomwindow();
protected:
    virtual void moveEvent(QMoveEvent *) override;
private:
    Ui::atomwindow *ui;
    PeriodicTable *table;
    bool tableshown = false;
};
```

atomwindow.cpp

```
void atomwindow::ShowTable(){
    table = new PeriodicTable(this);
    table->SetShowPos(windowpos, button_2pos, button_2height, button_2width);
    tableshown = true;
    table->exec();
}

void atomwindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event){
    if(tableshown){
        table->MovePos(windowpos, button_2pos, button_2height, button_2width);
    }
}
```

periodictable.h

```
class PeriodicTable : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PeriodicTable(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~PeriodicTable();
    void SetShowPos(QPoint, QPoint, int, int);
    void MovePos(QPoint, QPoint, int, int);
private:
    Ui::PeriodicTable *ui;
};
```

periodictable.cpp

```
void PeriodicTable::SetShowPos(QPoint parentpos, QPoint point, int buttonheight, int buttonwidth){
    this->setGeometry(curpoint.x(), curpoint.y(), width, height);
}

void PeriodicTable::MovePos(QPoint parentpos, QPoint point, int buttonheight, int buttonwidth){
    this->move(curpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Dialog; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class SubDialog;

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();

protected:
    void moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event);

signals:
    void signalMove( const QPoint &, const QPoint & );

private:
    SubDialog  *sub;
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Dialog.cpp

```
#include "Dialog.h"
#include "SubDialog.h"
#include <QMoveEvent>
#include "ui_Dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    sub = new SubDialog;
    connect( this, &Dialog::signalMove, sub, &SubDialog::slotMove );
    sub->show();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete sub;
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)
{
    emit signalMove( event->pos(), event->oldPos() );
}
```

SubDialog.h

```
#ifndef SUBDIALOG_H
#define SUBDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class SubDialog;
}

class SubDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SubDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SubDialog();

public slots:
    void slotMove( const QPoint &, const QPoint & );

private:
    Ui::SubDialog *ui;
};

#endif // SUBDIALOG_H
```

SubDialog.cpp

```
#include "SubDialog.h"
#include "ui_SubDialog.h"

SubDialog::SubDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SubDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SubDialog::~SubDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void SubDialog::slotMove( const QPoint &newPos, const QPoint &oldPos )
{
    auto x = newPos.x() - oldPos.x();
    auto y = newPos.y() - oldPos.y();

    QPoint pos( this->pos().x() + x, this->pos().y() + y );
    move( pos );
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: My approach is to use `sub->move()` directly in `moveEvent()`, which is the same as sending a signal to the subDialog to change the position of the subDialog. But the movement of the sub-dialog will have a delay that can be noticed by the naked eye. Usually I only use signals when the child window passes parameters to the parent window; is it faster to use the signal mechanism than directly calling the member functions of the child window?

Comment: The two approaches will get the same result. But the code above works very well on my Windows 10. So, could you show me your example code?

Comment: The code has been updated in the question

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<QT_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(Ui::Dialog)> ui;`

Comment: @Veasky I've tested your code on Windows 10 and it worked very well.

Comment: @AllenZHU Sad, that may be the reason for the animation effect of macOS; but thank you

Comment: @Veasky My pleasure.